# Internal Server Error 500 Bugzilla installation

Tags: cgi, debian, bugzilla

I followed this tutorial in [installing Bugzilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61935/how-do-i-install-bugzilla), I didn't encounter any problem not until I hit localhost/bugzilla in the URL. My `sites-available/default` config is as follows:

```
    #ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    Alias /bugzilla/ /var/www/bugzilla/
    <Directory /var/www/bugzilla>
            AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
            Options +Indexes +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
            DirectoryIndex index.cgi
            AllowOverride Limit
    </Directory>
    #<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    #       AllowOverride All
    #       Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    #       Order allow,deny
    #       Allow from all
    #</Directory>
```

And when tailing at `var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/bugzilla/index.cgi' failed
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `AllowOverride Limit` to `AllowOverride All`?

Comment: have you solved this ? and if you did how ?

Answer (score 4):

Changing `AllowOverride Limit` to `AllowOverride All` solved the entire problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me as well. While upgrading to 5.0.3 using git I encountered a 500 internal server error.  Changing bugzilla.conf in Apache from `AllowOverride Limit` to `AllowOverride All` and restarting Apache fixed the issue.